# Any effective way to write DRBFM for code changes?

Tags: c

Can anyone please let me know if you could write an effective DRBFM for code changes?

regards
Maddy

Answer (score 0):

I had to look up "DRBFM", it means "Design Review Based on Failure Mode" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRBFM

They seem to be talking about reviewing design before making tiny changes, in order to increase reliability

I guess one approach would be to write extensive automated functional tests that showed the project was good for functional requirements and then ensure that all revision control commits are broken up into as small as possible units.  When the tiny commit is made, all the tests run and you'd be able to see if the design change caused a failure

There is widespread use of this technique in agile methodologies such as xP and Scrum